# Mandrill adding unwanted unsubscribe footer

Tags: wordpress, mandrill

Even though I never created a rule to do so, Mandrill is adding the following text at the bottom of my emails:

> No longer interested email from Life With Calliope Dombrowski?. Please click here to unsubscribe

I've searched google and couldn't find an answer to this question.

Thanks!

Setup: Wordpress+wpMandrill+Email Subscribers.  wpMandrill enables Wordpress to send all outgoing emails through Mandrill.  Email subscribers is a Wordpress plugin which allows the management and sending of newsletters.

Answer (score 2):

That particular text isn't what's typically used by Mandrill for an unsubscribe footer. We do provide a generic footer that can be added, but the phrasing is different (and includes the specific recipient's address). It sounds like one of your other plugins is appending the footer, so you'll probably want to review all of the settings that are configured for those to determine where/how the footer is being added. The Email Subscribers plugin is likely adding that since it's designed for sending to your subscribers. As Stephen pointed out, you may also need to keep that on your emails since an unsubscribe link is required for any bulk mail you're sending through Mandrill.

Comment: You are so right!  Turns out Email Subscriber was adding it.  Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You can by removing the merge tag in the header, but best practice (and the way to prevent your domain as being flagged a spam domain) is to include your own if you're opting out of Mandrill's management.

Remember a number of countries legally require you to include your address, and an unsubscribe button at the bottom of your emails. If you don't, you could risk fines, and penalties in each jurisdiction.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24843106-Can-I-remove-the-List-Unsubscribe-header-from-emails-sent-through-Mandrill-

Comment: Thanks for the info, Stephen.  This time though, the text originated from within the Email Subscribers plugin I was using.

Comment: @bdombro Whoops. Glad you sorted it out though.